# Get other user jti for flask-jwt-extended

Tags: python, flask, jwt, flask-jwt, flask-jwt-extended

How to get 'jti', not mine but by the "username" ?
On registration/login jti for access and refresh were assigned to 'username'. 
All instructions and docs note only how to get my own jti to logout with smth. like this code:

```py
class UserLogoutRefresh(Resource):
    @jwt_refresh_token_required
    def post(self):
        jti = get_raw_jwt()['jti']
        try:
            revoked_token = RevokedTokenModel(jti = jti)
            revoked_token.add()
            return {'message': 'Refresh token has been revoked'},200
        except:
            return {'message': 'Something went wrong'}, 500
```

How to get jti for another user.
I suppose smth like:

```py
jti = get_raw_jwt(identity='someusername')['jti']
```

has to exist for this, who knows ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each token will have a unique jti, it’s not scoped per username. If the same user creates 3 tokens, all of them will have a different jti for example. If you want to have access to these jti then you will use the decode_token function when you create your token and save it in a datastore somewhere you can look it up later

Comment: When user log in, next occurs in Login class

access_token = create_access_token(identity=data['username'])
refresh_token = create_refresh_token(identity=data['username'])

I need to add possibility for admin to revoke those tokens, for the username

Comment: See the using a database to blacklist example for one way how that could look: https://github.com/vimalloc/flask-jwt-extended/tree/master/examples/database_blacklist

Comment: It will require to rebuild the code but it is what i need, thanks.